# Implementing multiple line code in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I've been trying to recreate some basic Python programs using Python. For example, using Python, I tell the user to input some code. That code goes through a series of tests to, so far, examine what function you want (I.e 'print'), and what you want to do with that function (in this case, printing what's in the quotes and parentheses). I also coded my program so that it can be easily added to and more functions can be added to the 'dictionary' my program determines your wanted function by. I'm trying to add code to upgrade my program from only accepting a single line of code to using this:

```
line_number=10
for number in range(1,line_number+1):
    inp=input(f"    Line {number}: ")
```

So far my program is this, and it's still in development:

```
def tutorial():
    print("Python Tutorial:\nType your program:")
tutorial()
def program():
    textbox=input()
    print("--------------")
    command=None #I put four different command variables for situations like this for example: print(len(pow(3,4)))
    command2=None
    command3=None
    command4=None
    letter_start=0
    letter_end=0
    command_end=0
    textbox_input=None
    print_type=1 #1 = string: 2 = variable

    #def defining_variable(string):


    #This system is like a dictionary and is very useful when adding new functions besides print.
    #The first "if" statement tests whether the function you want starts with P. This applies for the Print function.
    #If you wanted to use a function like "def", you could add a section for words that start with 'd', then 'de', then 'def'.

    if textbox.startswith('p'):
        if textbox.startswith("pr"):
            if textbox.startswith("print("):
                command=print #You can change what command is used
                if print_type == 1:
                    letter_start=7 #"letter_start" is the variable that holds the position of the first letter (not including parentheses "" or brackets())
                    command_end=5
                elif print_type == 2:
                    letter_start=6
                    command_end=5
            else:
                print("Only Print")
                program()
        else:
            print("Only Print")
            program()
    else:
        print("Only Print")
        program()
        

    if textbox.startswith('(', command_end):
        if textbox.startswith('("', command_end):
            if textbox.endswith(')'):
                if textbox.endswith('")'):
                    print_type=1
                    letter_end=textbox.index(')')-1
                else:
                    print(f"-->{textbox}<--: Missing quotes")
            else:
                print(f"-->{textbox}<--: Missing parenthesis") ;
        elif textbox.endswith(')'):
            if textbox.endswith('")'):    
                print(f"-->{textbox}<--: Missing quotes")
            else:
                print_type=2
                letter_end=textbox.index(')')
                
        else:
            print(f"-->{textbox}<--: Missing parenthesis")

    else:
        print(f"-->{textbox}<--: Missing parenthesis")
        
    textbox_input = textbox[letter_start:letter_end]

    try:
        command(textbox_input)
        print("--------------")
        program()
    except:
        print("ERROR")
program()
```

I tried creating the original Python error messages as well to inform the reader of their mistake. This program was intended as a tutorial for Python beginners. Thanks for any help!

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: How would I supposedly add in that piece of code that allows the user to input multiple lines of code like in normal Python. So far it can only accept a single line input like: print("Hello world").

Comment: either put the input inside a loop that appends the input in a list of commands, or allow the user to give a file with code and you just read from the file. How do you know when the user has finished inputting commands? A double Enter?

Comment: Another quick question; when you have the input() function in your program and you execute it, when the computer reaches your input() function, it will stop and wait for your answer before continuing. Is there a way to change that so that multiple input() functions could appear before the user having to answer them?

Comment: see my answer. you first input all your commands until you insert an empty line. then you iterate over the commands list and you call the function execute_command which will contain you code for executing a single command

Answer (score 0):

To allow the user to input multiple lines you can do something like this:

```
commands = []
while True:
  line = input()
  if line:
     commands.append(line)
  else:   #if the line is empty finish inputting commands
     break
```

then your main program should execute command after command, so you can do

```
for command in commands:
    execute_command(command)
```